# "nil can't be coerced into Fixnum" model error in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite, ruby-2.0

I am working on Q&A app in ruby on rails.
I am getting error as "nil can't be coerced into Fixnum" This application is working fine on heroku (Please see bottom for demo project link.)

here is my error:

```
nil can't be coerced into Fixnum
Extracted source (around line #28):

#26 - maximum_score = 0
#27 - survey.questions.each do |question|
#28 - maximum_score += question.answers.map(&:score).compact.max
#29 - new_filled_question = filled_questions.build :content => question.content
#30 - question.answers.each do |answer|
#31 - new_filled_question.filled_answers.build :content => answer.content, :score =>  answer.score


app/models/filled_survey.rb:28:in `+'
app/models/filled_survey.rb:28:in `block in custom_init'
app/models/filled_survey.rb:27:in `custom_init'
app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb:47:in `fill'
```

I already worked on "+=" but still no use.
here is my app/models/filled_survey.rb:

```
class FilledSurvey < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :filled_questions, :dependent => :destroy, autosave: true
  belongs_to :survey
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :filled_questions
  after_initialize :custom_init
  validates_associated :filled_questions

  scope :completed, -> { where(completed: true) }
  scope :uncompleted, -> { where(completed: nil) }

  def total_score
    sum = 0
    filled_questions.each do |filled_question|
      filled_answer = filled_question.filled_answers.find_by_id( filled_question.filled_choice.selected)
      if filled_answer
        sum += filled_answer.score
      end
    end
    sum
  end

  def custom_init
    # save those values since they could change
    self.name ||= survey.name
    if filled_questions.empty?
      maximum_score = 0
      survey.questions.each do |question|
        maximum_score += question.answers.map(&:score).max
        new_filled_question = filled_questions.build :content => question.content
        question.answers.each do |answer|
          new_filled_question.filled_answers.build :content => answer.content, :score => answer.score
          new_filled_question.build_filled_choice
        end
      end
      self.maximum_score = maximum_score
    end

  end
end
```

and here is my app/controllers/surveys_controller.rb

```
class SurveysController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_survey, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy, :fill]

  def index
    @surveys = Survey.all
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @survey = Survey.new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @survey = Survey.new(survey_params)

    if @survey.save
      redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully created.'
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

  def update
    if @survey.update(survey_params)
      redirect_to @survey, notice: 'Survey was successfully updated.'
    else
      render :edit
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @survey.destroy
    redirect_to surveys_url, notice: 'Survey was successfully destroyed.'
  end

  def fill
    # TODO check if current user has to fill tha last version, or some older
    if @survey.filled_surveys.empty?
      filled_survey = @survey.filled_surveys.create
    elsif @survey.filled_surveys.uncompleted.empty?
      # all are completed
      filled_survey = @survey.filled_surveys.create
    else
      # we have some uncompleted
      filled_survey = @survey.filled_surveys.uncompleted.first
    end
    redirect_to edit_filled_survey_path(filled_survey)
  end

  private
    def set_survey
      @survey = Survey.find(params[:id])
    end

    def survey_params
      params.require(:survey).permit(:name, questions_attributes: [:id, :content, :_destroy, answers_attributes: [:id, :score, :content, :_destroy]] )
    end
end
```

Example App on [github](https://github.com/tycoool/QADemo) and [herokuapp demo](http://qademo.herokuapp.com/)

Comment: Why sqlite? In that project you use `pg`.

Comment: So, locally you are using sqlite and on heroku postgres? I have some errors while migrate with your db in sqlite, so the obvious tip - to use postgres. It works fine for me.

Comment: So is it because question.answers.map(&:score) is nil, meaning you dont have any answers in your devel database so, when you try to add nil, it errors.

Comment: Hi @zishe yes project is also working fine, independently on local machine(sqlite) and heroku(pg). but we have not only exam MVC here, i am developing many MVC too.

Comment: hi @sonnyhe2002 Yes, it is because of nil stack. and it is about :score function. basically when QA project independently running, its is not giving any error (i can use Zero/0 value also for score). but what happen with other. i am entering the answers but still getting some error - because of answer value is not store in db. and it is behaving as nil for stack. any other solution - Appreciate !!

Comment: @zishe thanks man for running my project on ur machine and calculating d error. 
at-sonnyhe2002 thanks man for looking exact code functionality. 

Any other solution please. already stuck. trying to solve it.